# Unable to run python script with python3 and cronjob

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm trying to run a python script in cron but I'm unable to get it to run at the specified time, or at all with cron. This is the reference I used: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-schedule-python-scripts-with-cron-the-only-guide-youll-ever-need-deea2df63b4e

This is the cronjob:

30 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/python/script/xmlmod.py

I did not include a shebang in my python script because the reference didn't either. The script runs successfully when I put:

/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/python/script/xmlmod.py

The python is set to be executable: -rwxr-x----

Please help, happy to answer any questions. I've been at this for two days trying to find an answer.

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:0` near the top of your crontab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcron%5D+unable+to+run+cronjob

Comment: @roadowl That's hopelessly wrong for anything which isn't specifically producing an X11 display error.